# React native list view comes behind keyboard

Tags: listview, react-native

My ListView comes behind keyboard.

When you press on list item it will close the keyboard and again you need to press on it.

KeyboardAvoidingView is not working.

How to bring keyboard to front so that it will work on single press.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) with the `always` value to `ListView`. So keyboard will dismiss and row selected with just one tap.